# Undefined method `arel_table' for 'method':Module

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my application I have 2 models: sushi(table 1) and type_sushi(table 2) with foreign key in between. Everthing is running like I expected but when I am showing the table 1 data, it shows me the sushi type like your id (1, 2, 3) but I'd like to show the name of sushis type like this:

I'd like to show like the "Tipo sushi" like the name of the type (yaksoba, sashimi for exemple) and not the id (1, 4 for exemple).

Could you guys help me?

```
<% @sushis.each do |sushi| %>
    <%= sushi.name %>
    <%= sushi.price %>
    <%= sushi.tipo_sushi_id %> -> (Here is I need to change something I guess)
    <%= link_to 'Show', sushi %>
    <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_sushi_path(sushi) %>
    <%= link_to 'Destroy', sushi, method: :delete, dat`enter code here`a: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
<% end %>
```

> Update: I've updated *"sushi.tipo_sushi_id"* to *"sushi.tipo_sushi.name"* but I've got this message: **undefined method `arel_table' for TipoSushi:Module**.

Comment: You didn't provide any code in your question but I assume what you have to do is something like `sushi.sushi_type.name`.

Comment: Please fix the code formatting.

Comment: I think the code is formatted right now.

Answer (score 3):

I solved the problem by add in model/sushi.rb, the comand `belongs_to :tipo_sushi, class_name: SushiTipo`.

Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is explicitly written to show the ID. If you want to show the name, this...

```
<%= sushi.tipo_sushi_id %>
```

Is obviously not going to do it.

Instead, you need to load the related record and display its name:

```
<%= sushi.tipo_sushi.name %>
```

This assumes you've set up your associations correctly.

Comment: I did it before but I received this message when I go to the page:

"undefined method `arel_table' for TipoSushi:Module"

Comment: Did you name a model the same thing as your application?

Comment: I did not. The application name is sushiBar. The model name is tipo_sushi and another model is called sushi.

Comment: meagar, now I have this message when I open the page: "uninitialized constant Sushi::TipoSushi"